# Associative Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an issue and this is not something that I have ever used before.

This is a snippet of the code.

```
//Defined at top of file
var ships_array = [];

//Function later on

    function refreshJSON(){
    $.getJSON("scripts/getJSON.php", function(json){

      if(json){
        $.each(shiplist,function(i,item){
            $.each(item,function(j,subitem){
                var mmsi = subitem['mmsi'];
                ships_array[mmsi].lat = subitem['lat'];
                ships_array[mmsi].lon = subitem['lon']; 

            });
        });
     } 

    });

    }
```

The error I am getting is

> ships_array[mmsi] is undefined [Break
>   On This Error] ships_array[mmsi].lat =
>   subitem['lat'];

Is this the right way to use an associative array?  I have seen an example similar to this but I am going wrong somewhere!  At the end of it I want an array of Google Maps markers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to initialize the value at the hash key first

```
var mmsi = subitem['mmsi'];
ships_array[mmsi] = ships_array[mmsi] || {};
ships_array[mmsi].lat = subitem['lat'];
ships_array[mmsi].lon = subitem['lon'];
```

Comment: Works great,I don't understand the second line, can you point me to a reference or explain please?  Will accept when it lets me as it works!

Comment: The `||` symbol is `or`, when used in assignments it means if the first item evaluates to `false` assign the next one. So for `x = false || 'foo' || 'bar';` `x` gets the value `'foo'`.

Comment: The second line takes a logical OR between the array element - ships_array[mssi] and an empty object literal {}. The former to make sure that an existing object is not overwritten, the latter to ensure that an empty object exists.

Comment: Sure. The problem is that if ships_array @ mmsi is undefined, you can't possibly set .lat or .lon on it - that would be the same as trying to do `(undefined).lat = 'test'`. The second line is a common javascript pattern for assigning default values. `ships_array[mmsi] || {}` will return either `ships_array[mmsi]` if it is defined, or `{}` if it is not. This is then used to set `ships_array[mmsi]`. An equivalent alternative second line would be `if(!ships_array[mmsi]){ships_array[mmsi]={};}`. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Yes spot on, just getting to grips with JavaScript!

Comment: If you are looking for a great crash course, try this book: [Javascript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0596517742/)

Comment: Make sure that `var mmsi = subitem['mmsi']` is an integer or else you won't be populating the `ships_array` as expected. You won't be able to `for( i=0, i<ships_array.length, i++ )` over it. If it is not an integer use `var ships_obj = {}` then you will be able to `for( var i in ships_obj )` over it

Comment: @meouw actually, jQuery's each() function iterates properly over both arrays and objects. That being said, however, he is not iterating over `ships_array`, he is iterating over `shipslist` and `item`

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code like this:

```
//Defined at top of file
var ships_array = [];

//Function later on

    function refreshJSON(){
    $.getJSON("scripts/getJSON.php", function(json){

      if(json){
        $.each(shiplist,function(i,item){
            $.each(item,function(j,subitem){
                var mmsi = subitem['mmsi'];
                ships_array[mmsi] = {lat: subitem['lat'], lon:subitem['lon']};
            });
        });
     } 

    });

    }
```